# How to download PDFs from a list of URLs using the wget module?

Tags: python, pdf, wget

I have a Python script which scrapes URLs from a [website](http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/) with Selenium and stores them in a list. Now, I would like to download them with the `wget` module.

This is the relevant part of the code, where the script completes the partial URLs obtained from the website:

```
new_links = []
for link in list_of_links: # trim links
    current_strings = link.split("/consultas/coleccion/window.open('")
    current_strings[1] = current_strings[1].split("');return")[0]
    new_link = current_strings[0] + current_strings[1]
    new_links.append(new_link)

for new_link in new_links:
    wget.download(new_link)
```

The script doesn't do anything at this point. It never downloads any PDFs and displays no error message.

What did I do wrong in the second `for` loop?

As for the question whether `new_links` is empty. It is not.

```
print(*new_links, sep = '\n')
```

gives me links like these (here just four of many):

```
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=vPjrUnz0wbA%3D
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=dsyx6l1Fbig%3D
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Cb64W7EHlD8%3D
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=A4TKEG9x4F8%3D
```

A partial URL looks like:

```
/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=vPjrUnz0wbA%3D`
```

Then the "base URL" is added before it

```
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni
```

This is the relevant part of the code, which just comes before the code above, where it collects the partial URLs:

```
list_of_links = []    # will hold the scraped links
tld = 'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni'
current_url = driver.current_url   # for any links not starting with /
table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tableDocCollection')
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody tr") # get all table rows
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
    link = row.find_element_by_css_selector('li a[onclick*=pdf]').get_attribute("onclick") # get partial link
    if link.startswith('/'):
        list_of_links.append(tld + link) # add base to partial link
    else:
        list_of_links.append(current_url + link)
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is working.

Try upgrading your wget version to 3.2 and check

```
new_links = ['http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=vPjrUnz0wbA%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=dsyx6l1Fbig%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Cb64W7EHlD8%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=A4TKEG9x4F8%3D']

for new_link in new_links:
    wget.download(new_link)
```

Output: four files got downloaded with filenames pdf.php, pdf(1).php, etc.